# Tranpose of a mixed tensor

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, bilinear-form, transpose

If $(-)'$ denotes the transpose operation then for a type (1,1) mixed tensor ${T^a}_b$,
$\left({T^a}_b\right)'={T^b}_a$. Although this seems right I would like to be able to show this starting with a bilinear form $T:V^{*} \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $V$ is a $n$-dimensional vector space and $V^{*}$ is its dual. The set of bilinear maps with this property is a vector space which we can denote as $\mathcal{T}^1_1$. Any bilinear map $T \in \mathcal{T}^1_1$ can be written as,
$$
T(u^{*},v)={T^a}_b e_a \otimes e^b (u^{*},v)
$$
where $e_a$ (resp. $e^b$) are the basis vectors (resp. covectors) of $V$ (resp. $V^{*}$) and the tensor product is defined as,
$$
e_a \otimes e^b (u^{*},v) := u^{*}(e_a)e^b(v)
$$
If there is a formal definition of the transpose of a bilinear form in $\mathcal{T}^1_1$ then it should be possible to show that $\left({T^a}_b\right)'={T^b}_a$.

Comment: Consider $T':V\times V^*\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $T'(v,u^*)=T(u^*,v)$.

Comment: Thanks @blargoner. Following this definition I get ${{T'}_a}^b={T^b}_a$  since $T'(v,u^*)={{T'}_a}^b e^a \otimes e_b (v,u^*)$. I guess there is one small step from here to proving that ${{T'}^a}_b={T^b}_a$.